# I want to know your schedule for tomorrow

Tags: grammar

1. I want to know your schedule for tomorrow.
2. I want to know your schedule tomorrow.

---

What is the part of speech of 'for tomorrow'? Is it an adjective phrase? What is the difference between the two sentences? #1 means that I want to know your tomorrow's schedule right now, at this moment. #2 means that I want to know your schedule not today, but tomorrow.
Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The part of speech for 'for' in 'for tomorrow' is a preposition. In this case it's being used to indicate a purpose (That you want to know their schedule for tomorrow).

'I want to know your schedule for tomorrow' means that you want your schedule before tomorrow for some purpose.

'I want to know your schedule tomorrow' means that tomorrow you want them to tell you their schedule.